# Ajax Call in MVC Core2 Bad Request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm refracting a website over to MVC Core 2.  For most of my Ajax calls I've been using the .Get() shorthand with no problem.  I have one AJAX call that needs to use $ajax() and for some reason I keep getting a bad Request error.  Keep in mind this code is currently working in an aspx website (other than the changed url when I refactored).

```
function get_Data() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Home/Get_Index_Values",
        data: JSON.stringify(),
        dataType: "json"
    }) //End Ajax Call
.Done({})
.fail(function(ts){
alert(ts.response);
})
```

My method is in the Home Controller for now.  With the short hand .get() I've been using this signature with no problem:

```
public JsonResult Get_Index_Values()
{
 stuff here
}
```

That didn't work for this $ajax call so I've tried:

```
      [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Get_Index_Values()
```

This also didn't work.
I then tried and modified the ajax url to the following and matching the above controller methods signatures (lot of iterations here):

```
"Home/Get_Index_Values"
/Home/Get_Index_Values
/Get_Index_Values
Get_Index_Values
https://localhost:44339/Home/Get_Index_Values
```

All to no avail.  I can rewrite this to use the shorthand .get(), but I'm interested in getting this to work so I can see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem.  I had added a AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute in the start up file.  Because of this, the tokens were not matching.  Had to do the following to make it work:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
```

Got this info from http://www.talkingdotnet.com/handle-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/

Comment: Don't forget to configure the antiforgery service to look for the X-CSRF-TOKEN header:            services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");