# AJAX POST request Returning 400 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to send data to controller using POST method using jQuery AJAX. This is my code that is used to send data:

```
 $('#save_new').on('click', function () {
                var category_name = $('#new_category').val();
                var description = $('#new_description').val();

                $.ajax({
                         type: 'POST',
                         url:"/admin/news-category/addNew",
                         data: JSON.stringify({ category_name:     category_name  ,description:description}),
                         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                         dataType:'json',
                         success: function (ctct) {
                            alert("success function run,");
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Failed to save news category.");
                        }
                });
            });
```

This is my controller:

```
[Route("/admin/news-category")]
public class NewsCategoryController : Controller
{
    [Route("addNew")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult addNew(string category_name,string description)
    {
        NewsCategory news_category = new NewsCategory();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           // some statements here
            return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "News Category added successfully" });
        }
        return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Invalid input datas.Please enter valid datas and try again" });
    }
}
```

The execution has not reached the **addNew** action in the controller. What is the cause of the problem?

**UPDATE 1:** This is my **MapRoute** in **Startup**

```
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

UPDATE 2:This is how my Network tab looks like:
[image: Network tab during inspection]

Comment: can you post your startup with the MapRoutes specifically.

Comment: @mvermef I updated my question . Can you have a look at it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting that error because I added

```
 services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
            });
```

in **ConfigureServices** mehod in **Startup** class.

From view,I was not sending **AntiForgeryToken** as I am not using **Form** tag helper. By default, because of that **MiddleWare**, my action was checking for **AntiForgeryToken** which was not sent through **AJAX Request**. So, I removed Validation from **addNew** action using **[IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute]** .

```
[Route("addNew")]
  [HttpPost]
  [IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute]
```

This solved my problem. 
I hope this helps for others having the same problem.

Comment: That disables the security on AJAX calls, opening you up to CSRF attacks. You *can* (and should) send the token with the AJAX requests and set up the AntiForgery service to use it. See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48407537/1173702

Answer (score 0):

short answer: you will need to learning about route Maps and when to use them...

long answer: reference comment lines

```
  app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {

           routes.MapRoute(
             name: "newcatroute",
             template: "admin/news-category/{action}/{id?}"
             defaults: new {controller="NewsCategory", action="Index"]);

            //your route CAN'T be caught by default... because 
            //of the `admin/news-cateogry`since it doesn't know 
            //how to map that to any controller even with that route 
            //attribute attached to the Controller its self.               


            //HONEY POT ROUTE ... WORKS most of the time, unless you put some flashy extras in...!
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });



public class NewsCategoryController : Controller
{

   public IActionResult Index(){
         return View();
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult addNew(string category_name,string description)
   {
     //...
   }
}
```

with the above route map in place it will map any call to "admin/news-category" to that controller any actions associated with that control will be found.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#using-routing-middleware

Comment: I am able to access index action of the same controller using /admin/news-category/index . When I inspect I see that 400 error is shown in /admin/news-category/addNew  . I tried using the above said route too.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a problem with your parameters in the method signature.
By default, when using POST you should define the data you want to send in the message body. 
Therefore I recommend you to create a class which holds these parameters like this

```
public class MsgDto
{
    public string category_name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Then tell your method to read these values from the message body by using the FromBody attribute

```
[Route("addNew")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult addNew([FromBody]MsgDto msg)
{
    // read msg.category_name or msg.description
}
```

Comment: sorry sir that didn't work. I am running my app in HTTPS.  But when I remove HttpPost from action and send data through querystring, everything runs fine. But I want that to be HttpPost actually.

Comment: @DotNetdeveloper ok, strange.. Sounds like something is wrong then in the ajax request..Could you try with my solution and specifying the body as  JSON.stringify({ "category_name":category_name  ,"description":description})

Comment: sorry sir, that didn't help too. I have updated my question to show response and request headers. Could you please have a look at it?